# doing a docker build for the first time and ran into this massive error

Tags: linux, docker, centos, centos7

I am following [this django-docker tutorial](https://github.com/morninj/django-docker)

I ran the command in Centos 7:

```
docker build -t <insertyournamehere>/django-docker .
```

and ran into this massive error message:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Mwo_hq/pycparser/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-giTR8X-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Mwo_hq/pycparser/
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
```

InsecurePlatformWarning

Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to this!

Comment: `docker build ` uses a `Dockerfile`, in this case the Dockerfile was in the current directory when running `docker build`.  There could be literally any sequence of shell or other commands in there.   You would at least have to post the Dockerfile, and even then the question may be too broad.

Comment: https://github.com/morninj/django-docker I was using this tutorial, down to the letter, except for the sections involving apt-get, I would instead use yum.

Comment: It is not necessary to change `apt-get` to `yum` in the `Dockerfile` because the top line `FROM ubuntu:14.04` tells docker to download and begin with a standard ubuntu 14.04 container.  All the subsequent commands run in that ubuntu container, and it doesn't care if some other linux OS (like Fedora or Red Hat) is installed on the host.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/ I'm going to see if taking these steps to remove the old docker might be what I need.

Comment: do you know what I should be putting for <dockerhostname>?

Answer (score 0):

Docker improperly installed. Case closed.